# Como fazer efeito de zoom/afastamento lento de imagem?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá, estou tentando fazer em Javascript uma função que dê um `zoom` bem lento na minha imagem, ou seja, aumentando meu `background-size` lentamente, para dar impressão de movimento na imagem.

Tentei fazer essa função, mas ao rodar o site, fiquei sem nenhum sucesso.

```
function zoomLento(){
     var imagem = document.getElementById("imagem");
    for (var i = 100; i <= 200; i++){
        setTimeout(function(){
            imagem.style.backgroundSize = i;
        }, 10 * (i / 10))
    }
}
```

Comment: usa o `this.is(":hover") = this.style.scale(2);` e no css da um `transition:scale Ns ease-in-out;` (apenas usando hover como exemplo, tu pode usar tranquilamente outros atributos/propriedades/funções nativas)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu uso CSS transform para esse efeito

```
.div-com-bg{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(https://placehold.it/200x200);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position:center center;

    transition: background-size 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: background-size 1s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: background-size 1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: background-size 1s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: background-size 1s ease-in;

}

.div-com-bg:hover,
.div-com-bg.ativado{
    background-size: 150%
}
```

Eu fiz esse jsfiddle pra você ver como fica o efeito: https://jsfiddle.net/2utzegxf/1/

Comment: uma alternativa também é alterar a `scale` do elemento :)

Comment: O efeito não funcionou como esperado aqui :/ O meu css acusou erro na parte do `background-size 20s` e também só quando eu boto o mouse em cima da imagem que o zoom acontece. E ainda o zoom ta trocando pra `background-size: 150%` direto, ficando bem estranho. Alguma solução?

Comment: Viajei na maionese, coloquei transform ao invés de transition ... vou revisar o código e atualizar a resposta

Comment: Agora sim ta funcionando =)

Answer (score 1):

Testei aqui e aparentemente funcionou com este código:

```
function zoomLento(){
    var imagem = document.getElementById("imagem");
    for (var i = 100; i <= 200; i++){
        setTimeout(function(){
            zoom(imagem);
        }, 100 * (i / 10))
    }
}

function zoom(image){
    var width = image.width + 1;
    image.style.width = width + 'px';
    image.style.height = 'auto';
}

zoomLento();
```

Onde na função zoom eu adiciono 1 px cada vez que ela é chamada, e na função zoomLento eu chamo a função zoom 200 vezes, aumentando o tempo entre elas.